For a t-distribution, df = n-1. What does n represent?
Cross-posted from Math Stack Exchange as suggested by 2 people there.
I know that the $t$-distribution has one parameter: the number of degrees of freedom (df).
I also know that $\mathrm{df} = n - 1$.
However, what EXACTLY does the $n$ represent?
I have heard several meanings:

"The number of data points in your dataset." This doesn't sound right. If I have $100$ data points, but the $t$-distribution with $\mathrm{df}=50$ models the distribution better than $\mathrm{df}=99$, then why should I force the $\mathrm{df}$ to be 99?

"The number of normal random variables that you use to define the $t$-statistic from the sample mean $\bar{x}$." This doesn't sound right, either. I know that
$$t = \frac{\bar{x} - \mu}{s / \sqrt{n}}.$$
However, that looks more like a mathematical relationship rather than a definition of $t$. What if I don't start with the normal random variables?


